# How to compress only last week file and folder in Mac terminal

Tags: linux, macos, zip

suppose I have a folder \home\mybackup, structure in the folder is:

```
\home\mybackup\file1.txt
\home\mybackup\file2.txt
\home\mybackup\subfolder\<a lot of file and sub directory in subfolder>
```

I want to zip (or other compress way)  every file or sub folder in mybackup to a zip file if they are created or modofied within a week. the structure of them in mybackup should keep the same since I will unzip it later on to \home\mybackup_new. How to do that?

I goto \home\mybackup, tried:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -7 -exec zip -r zipfile2.zip {} +
```

but it shows error:

```
zip warning:   first full name: ./information/
                  second full name: information/
                 name in zip file repeated: information/
```

if I try:

```
find \home\mybackup -maxdepth 1 -mtime -7 -exec zip -r zipfile2.zip {} +
```

it zips everything regardless of date.